# Audio solution for working with motion capture

Tags: post-production

We are planning on doing a Motion Capture session where we record the Dialogue on the motion capture stage - The whole session with be time code synced so we will know what audio take will go with which motion data. Now here comes the fun part - The software (motion builder) which the animators use for editing the mo cap data is extremely cumbersome when editing both mocap data and audio at the same time, meaning that it is pretty impossible to do. However the mo cap time data will stay intact during the edits, meaning that we can extract a non continuous time code from the 'edited' animated scene. My question to you guys is :
1. have any of you guys and gals ever come across this problem before and have a solution?
2. Do any of you know of any software that will edit an audio file to a given set of time code data.

Any suggestions would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you fake an EDL from the mocap edit timecode? :]

Then maybe a product from SynchroArts or Maggot Software?

Comment: @georgi.m Thanks for your answer - We can get an EDL from the mocap, it would probably be in XML format. Seeing that there might be quite a few edits in a file and quite a few different segments - so is there any software that will actually cut the audio file along with the EDL?

Comment: check w Justin at Maggot, he's just finished work on Tintin which was 100% mocap...

Comment: @tim prebble & @georgi.m Brilliant Thanks very much I will chase these up :) - Tim do you have a contact for Justin? my email is richard(dot)lapington(at)Remedygames(dot)com